# Detecting duration of key-press using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, user-input

I'm very new to JavaScript, sorry if this is a dumb question, I haven't been able to find a good answer online.

I'm currently using:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { keys[e.keyCode] = true; });
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) { keys[e.keyCode] = false; });
```

to detect user input, which works quite well for my purpose, but I can't think of a good way to figure out how long a key has been pressed down.

I've tried putting a while-loop that exits if `keys[index]` returns false and increments a counter in the loop, but that just seems to break the script. I'm guessing I could write a function that specifically detects if the key I want has been released, but I'm not sure how to go about that properly.

Additionally, I only need to check it for one key.

Comment: Do you need to know how long it has been pressed before you release the key?

Comment: check `Date.now()` at keydown and at keyup

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of setting boolean values, set a timestamp on keydown, then retrieve it and compare against the current timestamp on keyup:

```js
const signalKeypressDuration = (key, duration) => {
  console.log(`Key ${key} pressed for ${duration} ms`);
};

const keys = {};
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", ({ key }) => {
  if (!keys[key]) keys[key] = Date.now();
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", ({ key }) => {
  signalKeypressDuration(key, Date.now() - keys[key]);
  keys[key] = null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. I was just about to try something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting in `true` in `keydown`, put `new Date()`.
Instead of putting in `false` in `keyup`, calculate `new Date() - keys[e.keyCode]` and store it somewhere.